# Spring. How bean injection works when there are more than one bean with the same qualifier?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Lets assume you have the following Classes extending the Processor interface:

```
Interface Processor {}

class ProcesorImpl1 implements Processor {}

class ProcesorImpl2 implements Processor {}
```

Now, Lets assume that you define the following bean in a configuration class in package1:

```
class ConfigurationClass1 {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("processor")
    public Processor processor() {
         return new ProcesorImpl1();
    }

}
```

Next, you define the following bean in a configuration class in package2:

```
class ConfigurationClass2 {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("processor")
    public Processor anotherProcessor() {
         return new ProcesorImpl2();
    }

}
```

The question is how does Spring resolves the following Injection:

```
@Inject @Qualifier("processor") proc;
```

What if one of the Beans are annotated with @Primary?

Answer (score 1):

`Qualifier` doesn't work with `@Bean` annotation, but `@Primary` does and it will define what concrete bean will be injected if you inject a bean by type and there is multiple bean of this type managed by Spring. If you want to inject another non-primary bean, you can mark it with `@Qualifier("beanName")` annotation to inject it by name.
If you define 2 bean with the same names and the same types like this

```
class ConfigurationClass1 {

    @Bean("processor")
    public Processor processor() {
         return new ProcesorImpl1();
    }

}

class ConfigurationClass2 {

    @Bean("processor")
    public Processor anotherProcessor() {
         return new ProcesorImpl2();
    }

}
```

Spring will override the first loaded bean within the second and only single will stay in container, because of `allowBeanDefinitionOverriding` property is set to `true` by default.